# C#: async in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, asynchronous, lambda

Good day. I need to execute some Task func async. But how to do this?

```
public async Task<string> GetPersonForSchedule(int[] usedStaff, string position)
{
    var result = await staffRepository
        .GetMany()
        .Where(async elem => await IsGoodPersonForSchedule(elem, usedStaff, position))
        .ToListAsync();

    return await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result));
}

private async Task<bool> IsGoodPersonForSchedule(Person person, int[] usedStaff, string position)
{
    //...
    var currPersonFlights = await flightStaffRepository
        .GetMany()
        .Include(elem => elem.Flight)
        .Where(elem => IsDateSuitable(elem.Flight.FlightDate.Value))
        .Include(elem => elem.Flight.Route)
        .ToListAsync();
    //...
    return true;
}
```

So, at the line `.Where(async elem => await IsGoodPersonForSchedule(elem, usedStaff, position))` i have an error:

> Cannot convert async lambda expression to delegate type `Func<Person,
>   bool>`. An async lambda expression may return void, Task or Task,
>   none of which are convertible to `Func<Person, bool>`.

I found this as solution:
`.Where(elem => IsGoodPersonForSchedule(elem, usedStaff, position).Result)`
But it is so strange, use Result property of async method... It compiles without errors. Maybe you know another solution?

Answer (score 1):

```
private async Task<bool> IsGoodPersonForSchedule(Person person, int[] usedStaff, string position)
{
    //...
    var currPersonFlights = await flightStaffRepository
        .GetMany()
        .Include(elem => elem.Flight)
        .Where(elem => IsDateSuitable(elem.Flight.FlightDate.Value))
        .Include(elem => elem.Flight.Route)
        .ToListAsync();
    //...
    return true;
}
```

Eh, either something important is being done in the elided bits here, or this can just be replaced with:

```
private Task<bool> IsGoodPersonForSchedule(Person person, int[] usedStaff, string position)
  => Task.FromResult(true)
```

And this is important because you can't push the task part of an operation into a subquery.

If however you have a non-async `IsGoodPersonForSchedule` and an async `IsGoodPersonForScheduleAsync` then you can use `IsGoodPersonForSchedule` within queries and it will become part of the whole query passed to the database. Obtaining the result of the larger query will be async as a whole.

E.g. let's assume that your `IsGoodPersonForSchedule` was something more like:

```
private Task<bool> IsGoodPersonForScheduleAsync(Person person, int[] usedStaff, string position)
{
    return flightStaffRepository
        .GetMany()
        .Include(elem => elem.Flight)
        .Where(elem => IsDateSuitable(elem.Flight.FlightDate.Value))
        .AnyAsync();
}
```

(Which is probably well off, but I just want an example of something that really does meaningfully get a boolean result from the repository async).

Then if you also had:

```
private bool IsGoodPersonForSchedule(Person person, int[] usedStaff, string position)
{
    return flightStaffRepository
        .GetMany()
        .Include(elem => elem.Flight)
        .Where(elem => IsDateSuitable(elem.Flight.FlightDate.Value))
        .Any();
}
```

That form could be used as part of a wider query, and because it's part of a wider async query then it is still turned into SQL when appropriate, rather than executed non-async within the C#.

The duplication of code is bad, but solvable:

```
private IQueryable<Flight> FlightsForPerson(Person person, int[] usedStaff, string position)
{
    return flightStaffRepository
        .GetMany()
        .Include(elem => elem.Flight)
        .Where(elem => IsDateSuitable(elem.Flight.FlightDate.Value));
}

private Task<bool> IsGoodPersonForScheduleAsync(Person person, int[] usedStaff, string position)
=> FlightsForPerson(person, usedStaff, position).AnyAsync();

private bool IsGoodPersonForSchedule(Person person, int[] usedStaff, string position)
=> FlightsForPerson(person, usedStaff, position).Any();
```

I'd also note that you have:

```
return await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result));
```

This is going to create yet another task that has to be run on another thread rather than the thread handling the previous `await`. It should be

```
return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result);
```

Comment: About creating thread for serialize to json: yep, i agree with you, creating new thread should take more time than executing this in current thread. Thank you for explanation about async in linq.

Answer (score -1):

The `Where` must get value in return because this is the way it can assert if the row is meeting the condition or not.

That's is way this `.Where(elem => IsGoodPersonForSchedule(elem, usedStaff, position).Result)` solution looks appropriate.